# debugging a vagrant setup bash script

Tags: bash, vagrant

I have a `Vagrantfile` with a setup script as below. I've run it several times with `vagrant up` and I know the first few commands work, but later ones I know did not succeed.

Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

$setup = <<END
  # some bash code
  # ...

  # something that somehow never runs
  sudo chown -R vagrant:vagrant /some/path
END

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "puppetlabs/centos-7.0-64-nocm"

  config.vm.define "client", primary: true do |client|
    client.vm.hostname = "client.example.com"
    client.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.250.10"
    client.vm.provision "shell", inline: $setup
  end
end
```

Is there any way to see what errors happen when scripts are run on `vagrant up`?

I tried `vagrant up --debug &> vagrant.log` but the output was literally thousands of lines and I couldn't find anything useful (or didn't know what to look for, which is more likely).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo` should do the trick and display messages from your shell file.

```
echo "running update ..."
sudo apt-get update

echo "running install lib  ..."
sudo apt-get install --yes git-all libreadline-dev build-essential curl git m4 python-setuptools ruby texinfo libbz2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libexpat-dev libncurses-dev zlib1g-dev

echo "install rvm ..."
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby=2.0.0
```

all echo messages will be displayed in the output when running the shell provisioning

If you need to redirect stderr to stdout you can do something like `grep * 2>&1` -
ref: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html

Answer (score 2):

While Frédéric Henri's answer is definitely recommended and helpful, vagrant also comes with some built in debugging help which you can [read more about here](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/other/debugging.html), but basically you can `vagrant up` with a debug flag for more information:

```
vagrant up --debug
```

Comment: @lollercoaster Fair enough. You could try looking on the Guest for logs (dmesg, syslog, /var/log/*, etc.). That, combined with the echo's in Frédéric Henri's answer should help you narrow down what is failing during the provision. You can also try grepping the vagrant.log for "error" - `cat vagrant.log | grep -i error` to see if that helps narrow it down.